# Unit testing rendering context. Page context throws an exception

Tags: sitecore, moq

I am trying to create unit test using sitecoreFakeDB my code displays below:

```
using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db() { new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("source") })
        {
            var contextItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/source");
            var args = new Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs();
            using (RenderingContext.EnterContext(new Rendering(), contextItem))
            {

                var processor = new Mock<Sitecore.FakeDb.Pipelines.IPipelineProcessor>();

                db.PipelineWatcher.Register("mypipeline", processor.Object);

                Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("mypipeline", args);

                Xunit.Assert.NotNull(args.Current));
            }
        }
```

upon checking the pagecontext in the RenderingContext.Current it throws an exception. How can I have a value for the pagecontext?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no `PageContext.EnterContext` method similar to the one used for entering the rendering context. You may set it manually via the `ContextService` static class (but beware the possible garbage if you won't clean it up properly):

```
ContextService.Get().Push(new PageContext());
var currentContext = RenderingContext.Current;
Assert.NotNull(currentContext.PageContext); // pass
```